# In the dash app, can href be implemented in to the value within in dcc.Dropdown?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a dropdown page selector in a multi page dash app. The dropdown selection should generate an updated html depending on the user selection. The issue that I'm running in to is that I do not know how to use href within the value selection of dcc.Dropdown.

The code below is my current example that is not working.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    html.Div([

        html.H2('Equipment Maintenance & Repair Dashboard'),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(id='page_dd',
                         options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x, y in page_info.items()])
        ])
    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

If I use dcc.Link instead of dcc.Dropdown, then the output is successful. See the example below, which properly changes the html following the user selection.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    html.Div([

        html.H2('Equipment Maintenance & Repair Dashboard'),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Link('Trend ', href='/apps/dispatch_trend'),
            dcc.Link('Equipment ', href='/apps/equipment_overview')
        ])
    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url to change based on the dropdown selection you need to create callback

```
@app.callback(Output("url", "pathname"), Input("page_dd", "value"))
def update_url_on_dropdown_change(dropdown_value):
    return dropdown_value
```

Complete example

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H2("Equipment Maintenance & Repair Dashboard"),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="page_dd",
                            options=[
                                {"label": "Trend", "value": "/apps/dispatch_trend"},
                                {
                                    "label": "Equipment",
                                    "value": "/apps/equipment_overview",
                                },
                            ],
                        )
                    ]
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("url", "pathname"), Input("page_dd", "value"))
def update_url_on_dropdown_change(dropdown_value):
    return dropdown_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```